# Aligning Tkinter checkbutton text characters to left

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm using Python 2.7 to display 2 `Checkbuttons`. If I use `justify = LEFT` it displays an error `"global name 'LEFT' is not defined"`

```
class simple_ap(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):


        Checkbutton = Tkinter.Checkbutton(self,text='All_1',width = 50,justify = LEFT)
        Checkbutton.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        Checkbutton = Tkinter.Checkbutton (self,text='To_check_for_the_space_between_brackets',width = 50)
        Checkbutton.grid(column = 0, row = 8)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simple_ap(None)
    app.title('my_app')
    app.mainloop()
```

Is this the correct way to use "justify"?
I worked off of http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_frame.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears as if you are using `import Tkinter` rather than `from Tkinter import *`, which is used in the sample you linked.

You need to use `Tkinter.LEFT`.